# PostgreSQL JDBC driver hide prepared statement parameters from logging

Tags: postgresql, logging, jdbc

I need to hide prepared statement parameters from logging debug level and exception message. There are security critical values. For example using `pgp_sym_encrypt`, when exception thrown from database, in exception message shown full statement with parameters also 2nd parameter encryption key password. 
Is there any way to hide these kind of values, especially in exception message?

Comment: Have you considered passing the encryption key as a parameterized value?

Comment: Yes, 2nd parameter as encryption key to `pgp_sym_encrypt`

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to do the encryption on the client side and never send the password to the database.  Once you send it to the database, it will be very hard to absolutely control what happens to it.  Consider that if there is a way to configure the database to suppress this logging, then there is also a way to reverse that configuration.